# Problems with float and max-width

Tags: html, css

I try to build a layout with 2 floating DIV´s on higher resolution and without floating on small resolution. One (subnavigation) with a fixed width and one (content) with a max-width.

here is an example code of the HTML:

```
<div id="subnavigation">
   lorem ipsum...
</div>
<div id="content">
   lorem ipsum...
</div>
```

and here the CSS:

```
#subnavigation {
   float:right;
   width:320px;
}
#content {
   max-width:730px;
}
@media only screen and ( max-width:800px ) {
   #subnavigation, #content {
      float:none;
      width:auto;
   }
}
```

My problem now is that I need the subnavigation below the content without the float. Have someone an idea?
I tried a little bit with the calc() in CSS to get a fixed width for the content (to be able to float that), but it doesn't really work on my android-phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use some [negative](http://alistapart.com/article/negativemargins) [margin](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) [sorcery](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/).

Heres one way to approach it (probably a bit overcomplicated)

HTML

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            ..content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        ..content..
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page {
    width:1050px; /*320px + 730px*/    
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:grey;
}

.content-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.content {
    margin-right:320px;
    background:orange;
}

.sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:320px;
    margin-left:-320px;
    background:green;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
    .content-wrapper {
        float:none;
        width:auto;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    .content {
        margin-right:0;    
    }
    .sidebar {
        float:none;
        margin:0;
        width:auto;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/vV4LT/